# Is circuit cutting equivalent in anyway to quantum teleportation?

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, teleportation

I've been introduced recently to circuit cutting, and after seeing the 4 orthogonal measurements with their 8 corresponding initializations but no initial transfer of classical info, the first thing that came to my mind was that this was pretty similar to quantum teleportation.

And I wanted to know how similar are they, or are they not? Is there any obvious mapping I'm not understanding between telling the initial state in quantum teleportation and initializing in the 8 orthonormal eigenstates, that makes them equivalent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I feel as though one could come up with trivial examples where there is no teleportation: take any algorithm that naturally breaks up into different cut circuits. But I am also interested in whether *some* circuit cutting algorithms are equivalent to quantum teleportation, or rely more heavily on it than others

Comment: If you have a working example of circuit cutting - I'd appreciate it. Available papers are just super hard to comprehend.

Comment: @rhundt Hey I think that where I learned it, had pretty good resources, check this repo out:
https://github.com/QuantumBarcelona/Qiskit-Hackathon-BCN/blob/main/challenges/BSC_challenge.ipynb

Comment: The repo itself link these two papers:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.02333  https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00102

Comment: @QuantumMechanic yeah exactly, that was what I was wondering, they are two completely different processes, but effectively (in a theoretical quantum computer with no errors) you get the same results doing circuit cutting, as if you where sending the quantum state classically (via teleportation).

Comment: @rhundt and if you want the answers to the questions in the repo, check this other branch (team 10), it is the answers we arrived to during the hackathon: https://github.com/QuantumBarcelona/Qiskit-Hackathon-BCN/blob/team10/challenges/BSC_challenge.ipynb

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_quantum_circuit_cutting.html